# How to make Collection property hold various types of subclasses

Tags: c#, winforms, object-model

I've written a .NET component which includes a property of type `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<MainClass>`. `MainClass` itself has many subclasses called `Derived1`, `Derived2` etc. After compiling, I click on this property in designer and when I try to add a new item, an instance of `MainClass` is created all the time. I want to prompt the user and ask what type of item they intend to insert. I tried to override `InsertItem(int index, SearchableField item)` but it cannot change the item.

This exact behavior is implemented in `DataGridView.Columns` property. When you click Add in the columns editor, a dialog is shown and type of new item is asked from programmer.

Comment: Why do you need to change the item?  Derived1, Derived2, etc. are all also instances of MainClass.  Do you need to call functions that are only in the derived classes?

Comment: Obviously the special properties of them are needed.

Comment: How do you intend to keep track of which derived class is at each entry in your collection so that you will know what to cast them to and enable access to the specialized functions?

Comment: There's no virtual method to call. I only need their properties. Have you seen how changing `ColumnType` in `DataGridView.Columns` works in designer?

Comment: I switched to WPF years ago, but looking now at a WinForm app the choices are limited to 6 column types and what you seem to be asking for is an unlimited number of choices as long as they are derived from MainClass. Correct?

Comment: No they're limited and known. Just like DataGridView.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109281/discussion-between-clay-ver-valen-and-javid).

Answer (score -1):

Would the following work for you?  You'll need to add code to size the array appropriately, but each entry in `instances` will hold either `Derived1` or `Derived2` when `Main` exits.

```
using System;

public abstract class MainClass { }
public class Derived1 : MainClass { }
public class Derived2 : MainClass { }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Array instances = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(MainClass), 5);

        instances.SetValue(AddItem(typeof(Derived1)), 0);
        instances.SetValue(AddItem(typeof(Derived2)), 1);
        instances.SetValue(AddItem(typeof(Derived1)), 2);
        instances.SetValue(AddItem(typeof(Derived2)), 3);
        instances.SetValue(AddItem(typeof(Derived1)), 4);
     }

    static MainClass AddItem<T>(T type) where T : Type
    {
        return (MainClass)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is not related to my question at all, also these are C# basics; not to mention you haven't even used generic structures and this code is dirty :)

Comment: I specifically asked you in the chat session if you were OK with Array (which implements ICollection) and you wrote you were OK rewriting code.  Additionally, you did not state in your question that the use of a generic collection was requirement.  Please rewrite the question to enable other's to provide answers more suited to your particular needs.

Comment: The question is clear enough. You didn't even consider the tag `winforms` and you wrote a simple console application whilst the whole question is about Windows Forms behavior! Anyway, thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: Take a look at the [source code](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/fx/src/Designer/WinForms/System/WinForms/Design/DataGridViewAddColumnDialog@cs/1/DataGridViewAddColumnDialog@cs) for DataGridViewAddColumnDialog at the AddColumn function.  You'll see that it uses Activator.CreateInstance and then casts the result as the super class - just like my answer. It does not use generics either.  I don't have the inclination to write an entire custom control to demo this, that's why the console app.

Comment: Of course it'd use `Activator.CreateInstance` because there's no other way. The most important part is what data structure is used. Thanks to you I checked the source code and unlike what you said it was not an array. I dug more into it and found out that it's using:`BaseCollection, IList`

Comment: And the backing store for the List property in [BaseCollection](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/BaseCollection.cs) is a System.Collections.ArrayList.